# Get Store View id or code in plugin in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0, store-view, plugin

I want to write a plugin which executes a code only if a specific `store view` is active.
I have read in the [magento docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#limitations%22magento%20docs%22), that `__construct` is not allowed in plugins.
**How can I get the `store view` in a plugin?**

Comment: `$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$storeManager  = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currentStore  = $storeManager->getStore();
$storeId       = $storeManager->getStore()->getId(); // Store Id` Works?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I used the solution from below, without `ObjectManager`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you misread the documentation. Basically the following are plugins limitations:

> - Objects that are instantiated before `Magento\Framework\Interception` is bootstrapped
> - Final methods
> - Final classes
> - Any class that contains at least one final public method
> - Non-public methods
> - Class methods (such as static methods)
> - `__construct`
> - Virtual types

**That does not mean you cannot use `__construct()` in your plugin class, that means you cannot create a plugin ON a `__construct()` method.**

To answer your question, you can inject the following in your constructor to get the store view:

```
protected $_storeManagerInterface;

public function __construct(...
     \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterf‌​ace $storeManagerInterface
    ...)
{
    $this->_storeManagerInterface = $storeManagerInterface;
    ...
}
```

Then in your code you can do:

```
$currentStore = $this->_storeManagerInterface->getStore();
$currentStoreId = $currentStore->getId();
```

Comment: Oh, thanks... Seems like I misunderstood something...

Comment: I get [ReflectionException]                                             
  Class Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterf‌​ace does not exist

Comment: @MohammedGomma you probably forgot the first backslash

Comment: I did it as your example exactly

Comment: @MohammedGomma try to flush `var/di`

Comment: I did setup:di:compile, Do you mean remove manually